# Branch out or split Politics into more specific subfields?

Tags: discussion

Not duplicating [Should Politics SE be split into two separate stack exchanges?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1495/35218). Just wondering why the [computer science and programming S.E. have specialized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598), but not politics?

As a starter, can't we bi-furcate Politics (specific to a country) with Political Science or Theory (not specific to any country)?

Comment: What would be the gain from doing any of this? In order for it to be considered you should include what would the site gain from it.

Answer (score 3):

Politics is still in beta. It currently has [around 7 questions a day](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#questionsperday) and an [answer ratio of 2.3](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) which isn't bad, but also not that high. If we were to split politics into two or more subs, that rate would likely go down significantly and would likely result in one or more of the subs remaining in beta indefinitely (or being closed completely).

On the other hand, it made a lot of sense to split subs off of stack overflow, which has 5300 questions a day.

Comment: Isn't it still in beta? It still has "Politics Beta" in the title?

Comment: @DanScally I was sure it was graduated last year, but it seems my memory isn't what it used to be. You are right, I'll update my answer.